# Remove tab index from off-screen elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a carousel component which should be able to scroll through an array of items.  I need the component to be accessible so I want my items to have a tab index. However if the element is not currently in the field of view, either the user should not be able to tab onto that element or tabbing to that element should cause the carousel to automatically scroll.

I am currently setting a ref on my carousel items, however I don't know how to use this ref to change the tab index on off screen elements.

My Item component looks like this:

```
export const Card = ({
    cypressTestId,
    bodyText,
    footerComponent,
    headerComponent,
    onClick,
}) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        //if ref element off screen set tab index -1
    });

    function renderBody() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Text type="h4">{bodyText}</Text>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function renderFooter() {
        return <div>{footerComponent}</div>;
    }

    function renderHeader() {
        return <div>{headerComponent}</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div
            className={styles.cards}
            data-cy={cypressTestId}
            onClick={onClick}
            tabIndex="0"
            onKeyPress={
                /* istanbul ignore next */ (e) => handleKeyPress(e, onClick)
            }
            ref={ref}
        >
            {renderHeader()}
            <div>
                {renderBody()}
                {renderFooter()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-rubin-nkgp5x?file=/src/styles.module.scss